# What is the utility of this kind of implementation of data structures using functions?

Tags: haskell

I'm implementing a Set using functions of type `a -> Bool`

Here is my code so far:

```
data Set a = S (a -> Bool)

empty :: Set a
empty = S (const False)

singleton :: Eq a => a -> Set a
singleton e = S (e ==)

belongs :: Set a -> a -> Bool
belongs (S s) = s

-- private
_combine :: (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
_combine op f g = \x -> f x `op` g x
----------

union :: Set a -> Set a -> Set a
union (S s1) (S s2) = S (_combine (||) s1 s2)

intersect :: Set a -> Set a -> Set a
intersect (S s1) (S s2) = S (_combine (&&) s1 s2)

add :: Eq a => a -> Set a -> Set a
add e = union (singleton e)

remove :: Eq a => a -> Set a -> Set a
remove e = intersect (complement (singleton e))

complement :: Set a -> Set a
complement (S s) = S (not . s)

universe :: Set a
universe = S (const True)

toSet :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a
toSet = S
```

But I can't implement the cardinal of a set, so I was wondering if these types of implementations have a useful use case, compared as a data structure implemented with lists, for example.

Comment: Why would that not be useful? For a lot of (mathematical) sets, it is hard to determine the number of elements (or even impossible).

Comment: I edited the question a little bit. I mean, compared to storing the elements of the set on a data structure like lists or trees.

Comment: Well, this implementation allows you to represent many things you can't with a backing type like `[]`. You can have the set of all even Integers or all Strings with length 5 or greater. You have to make some tradeoffs, but it's not like you don't get anything in return.

Comment: For finite sets, I'd consider this to be an "executable specification", i.e. an implementation that is so simple to be obviously correct, and that could be used as a reference implementation to be compared against a more realistic and performant implementation of sets. This is helpful in the case where one wants to make formal correctness proof of the "real" implementation. Another use is to teach FP, since it is so simple, even if it's inefficient. I'd probably not use this implementation for finite sets for many other tasks.

Comment: Sidenote: pretty sure `_combine` is just `liftA2` via the `(->) a` monad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, if your definition of "Set" simply means "a thing I can check for inclusion". Treating `a -> Bool` as a "Set" type means it can do one thing only. It certainly can't have a cardinality function, nor can it be iterated over. Mathematically, that's all a "Set" is, is an object that responds to the element-of operator ∈. But from a programming perspective, we've come to expect a bit more of our collections, such as the above operations.

On the other hand, as you've already noted, you can get pretty far with this collection. If you have two sets, you can take their intersection, their union, their difference, and their symmetric difference.

Your type is also somewhat bizarre by collection standards in how it acts as a functor. Most Haskell collections implement [`Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor), but yours never can. In fact, yours is just the opposite: a [`Contravariant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#t:Contravariant) functor.

```
instance Contravariant Set where
    contramap f (S p) = S (p . f)
```

So, by collection standards, this is a very unique data structure. It's still a useful one, but it behaves nothing like `[]` or the other conventional ones that store data in memory.

Comment: "It certainly can't have a cardinality function, nor can it be iterated over." - Except [when it can](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.1.3.1/docs/Data-Universe-Class.html#t:Finite).

Comment: Also keep in mind that Contravariant can be derived via [`Op Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#t:Op): `newtype Set a = Set (a -> Bool) deriving Contravariant via Op Bool` and we have two options for deriving Semigroup, Monoid, Divisible and Decidable: via `Op All` or `Op Any`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to actually answer the question, which was about when the function-based definition is more useful than a data-structure based definition.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That class would also make a `Functor` instance possible, though amusingly it would probably best be implemented by roundtripping through a more standard representation. But the more interesting part of this observation to me is that there may be existing `Functor` instances that could potentially have `Finite`-based `Contravariant` instances! How odd.

Comment: @DanielWagner yes. It's not _that_ odd though, since for any function on a finite types we can compute preimages, thus getting an arrow in the opposite direction.